# What's the difference between single quote and double quote to define a string in powershell

Tags: powershell

Simple questions that's been bugging me: In powershell, I can define strings like so:

```
$s1 = "Boogety boo"
```

or

```
$s2 = '.net rocks'
```

Is there a difference to the interpreter?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Double quotes allow variable expansion while single quotes do not:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $mycolor="red"
PS C:\Users\Administrator> write-output -inputobject 'My favorite color is $mycolor'
My favorite color is $mycolor
```

Source: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Windows_PowerShell_1.0_String_Quoting_and_Escape_Sequences

(I know version 1.0 but the principle is still the same)

Comment: The variable expansion that onteria_ refers to is also called "[interpolation](http://www.powershellpro.com/powershell-tutorial-introduction/variables-arrays-hashes/)".  You could also think of interpolation as "a specialized instance of concatenation", as brought out by [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_(computer_science)#Interpolation).

Comment: See also: [Variable expansion in strings and here-strings](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/07/15/variable-expansion-in-strings-and-herestrings.aspx) by Jeffrey Snover, which goes into more detail on using variables with strings.

Comment: In general, UNIX/Linux shells work in the same way with quoting.

Answer (score 10):

This is not trying to be a better answer. Just another way to say it.

The variable expansion between apostrophes and quotes are the same as on UNIX shells (sh, ksh, bash). Using apostrophes will take the character string as-is, without processing any escapes.

```
PS C:\Users\lit> $x = "`t"
PS C:\Users\lit> $x

PS C:\Users\lit> Write-Output "now${x}is"
now     is
PS C:\Users\lit> $x = '`t'
PS C:\Users\lit> $x
`t
PS C:\Users\lit> Write-Output "now${x}is"
now`tis
PS C:\Users\lit> $word = "easy"
PS C:\Users\lit> "PowerShell is $word"
PowerShell is easy
PS C:\Users\lit> 'PowerShell is $word'
PowerShell is $word
```

Answer (score 2):

This question has a direct answer in the [about_Quoting_Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules) article of the PowerShell docs:

> ## Double-quoted strings
>
> A string enclosed in double quotation marks is an *expandable* string. Variable names preceded by a dollar sign (`$`) are replaced with the variable's value before the string is passed to the command for processing.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> $i = 5
> "The value of $i is $i."
> ```
>
> The output of this command is:
>
> ```
> The value of 5 is 5.
> ```

> ## Single-quoted strings
>
> A string enclosed in single-quotation marks is a *verbatim* string. The string is passed to the command exactly as you type it. No substitution is performed. For example:
>
> ```
> $i = 5
> 'The value of $i is $i.'
> ```
>
> The output of this command is:
>
> ```
> The value of $i is $i.
> ```

In other words, use single quotes if you want your string to remain as written. Use double quotes, if you want to insert variables (`$myVariable`), results of command executions and other evaluations (`$($myList -join ', ')`) or special characters (`` `r ``, `` `n ``, `` `t ``, `` `a ``, etc.).