# Powershell < symbol in property name

Tags: powershell, import

I am processing a csv file in powershell which looks like this:

```
<TICKER>,<DTYYYYMMDD>,<TIME>,<OPEN>,<HIGH>,<LOW>,<CLOSE>,<VOL>
AUDJPY,20010102,230100,64.30,64.30,64.30,64.30,4
AUDJPY,20010102,230300,64.29,64.29,64.29,64.29,4
<snip>
```

I am using `Import-Csv` to process the file and I want to find return `<DTYYYYYMMDD>` values greater than 20110101. I tried this:

`foreach($file in ls $PriceFolder\*.txt) {Import-Csv $file | Where-Object {$_.<DTYYYYMMDD> -ge 20110101}}`

but I get this error

`Missing property name after reference operator.` I presume it's because of the < symbol? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Use {} to enclose not standard field names (or store them in a variable and refer as $_.$var);
2) Cast the value to [int] in order to avoid issues (data are read as strings from .csv; in this example this is not a problem perhaps but..)

This works:

```
Import-Csv test.csv | Where-Object {[int]$_.{<DTYYYYMMDD>} -ge 20010102}
```

Comment: Thanks that works, the file I am processing has over 4 million lines in it. What's the fastest way of processing it? All I want to do is copy lines to a new file where the `<DTYYYYMMDD>` column is greater than 20110101. It is quite slow using this method. Should I use `Out-File`? Is `Import-Csv` the best way?

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386793/how-to-use-powershell-to-reorder-csv-columns/6387587#6387587

Comment: And if your data are not trivial then consider to use, say, Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser

Comment: Great, it's faster but still much slower than a C# method I wrote using the same classes. Why's that? I'm using `System.IO.StringReader` to read the file, `System.IO.StringWriter` to write out each line that I want.

Comment: Actually I'll write another question for this.

Comment: What's the range of dates in the file?  Doing a regular expression match on the lines would probably be a lot faster.

Comment: Date range is from 20010101 to the present day, with 1 row for each minute since then. Would you mind posting an example as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can quote the property name:

```
$_.'<DTYYYYMMDD>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as a comment on MrKWatkins' answer, in one case single quotes work but double quotes don't work (in version 2.0 at least):

**Single Quote:**

```
(dir | Select-Object {$_.Name})[0].'$_.Name'       # GOOD: correctly gives name
```

**Double Quote:**

```
(dir | Select-Object {$_.Name})[0]."$_.Name"       # BAD: returns nothing
```

**Edit:** Double Quotes allow variable expansion whereas single quotes do not.  For more details see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967407/whats-the-difference-between-single-quote-and-double-quote-to-define-a-string-i).