# Run Reg.exe in PS script will not work on remote machine ERROR: Invalid key name

Tags: powershell

If I run the command from with in the script

> ```
> reg add "HKU\$sid\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v AutoConfigURL /t REG_SZ /d "http://mydomaon.com/proxies/proxy.pac" /f
> ```

it works perfectly, because it is local.

When I try to change the same registry key on a remote machine and changing the line to this

> ```
> reg add "\\$machinename\HKU\$sid\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v AutoConfigURL /t REG_SZ /d "http://mydomaon.com/proxies/proxy.pac" /f
> ```

It fails with 
**ERROR: reg : ERROR: Invalid key name. + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ERROR: Invalid key name.:String) [], RemoteException
ERROR:     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError**

```
ForEach ($machine in $machines)
{

    $User = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($env:UserName)
    $sid = $User.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).value
    New-PSDrive HKU Registry HKEY_USERS
#       Get-Item "HKU:\${sid}"
    Set-Location HKU:\
    cd HKU:\
    reg add '$SID\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings' /v AutoConfigURL /t REG_SZ /d 'http://proxy.domain.com/proxies/proxy.pac' /f

}
```

Comment: variables in '' will not be interpreted, what happens if you put the $sid part in "" or assemble it beforehand?

Comment: @Paul is right. This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967407/whats-the-difference-between-single-quote-and-double-quote-to-define-a-string-i) covers the quote issue easily

Comment: have you tested the command by typing it manually with fixed values?

Comment: It works perfectly when I put the computer in and put the known sid I am looking for.  See below

Comment: PS C:\> reg add "\\remote_computer\HKU\S-1-5-21-557486866-382535363-1543835964-500\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion
\Internet Settings" /v AutoConfigURL /t REG_SZ /d "http://blabla.com/proxies/domain.pac" /f                                                                               
The operation completed successfully.

Comment: hi kent, see my answer below. I figured before i try to find an error in your code (which i dont see on the first look) i might as well give you a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach that should work (also better then using reg.exe):

Local Computer:

```
New-PSDrive -Name HKU -PSProvider Registry -Root Registry::HKEY_USERS
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKU:\$sid\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" -Name      AutoConfigURL -PropertyType String -value "http://proy.domain.com/proxies/proxy.pac" -Force
```

Remote Computer:

```
$credential = Get-Credential
Foreach($machine in $computers){

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $machine -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock {$temp = $args[0];
    New-PSDrive -Name HKU -PSProvider Registry -Root Registry::HKEY_USERS; New-ItemProperty -Path "HKU:\$temp\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" -PropertyType String -Name AutoConfigURL -Value "http://proy.domain.com/proxies/proxy.pac" -Force} -argumentlist $sid
}
```

Also here are the Type mappings for `New-Itemproperty`´s `-PropertyType`:

> REG_SZ = String
>
> REG_DWORD = DWord
>
> REG_QWORD = QWord
>
> REG_MULTI_SZ = MultiString
>
> REG_BINARY = Binary

So after a few problems here is an updated version which should do everything including determining the local users sid by username (added linebreaks for readability, remove them when you copy)

```
$username = "yourUsername"
$credential = Get-Credential
Foreach($machine in $computers){

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $machine -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock {$temp = $args[0];
    New-PSDrive -Name HKU -PSProvider Registry -Root Registry::HKEY_USERS; 
    $sid = (Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_UserAccount | where {$_.Name -eq $temp} | select SID).SID;
    New-ItemProperty -Path "HKU:\$sid\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" -PropertyType String -Name AutoConfigURL -Value "http://proy.domain.com/proxies/proxy.pac" -Force
    } -argumentlist $username

}
```

After furhter discussion with Kent and clearly specifying the environment (Windows XP domain-joined machines, user logged on) the script has to run in this was what we came up with:

(this works only if the user is logged in on XP)

```
$sid = ((get-aduser $username).SID).Value 
$credential = Get-Credential
Foreach($machine in $computers){

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $machine -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock {New-PSDrive -Name HKU -PSProvider Registry -Root Registry::HKEY_USERS; New-ItemProperty -Path "HKU:\$($args[0])\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" -PropertyType String -Name AutoConfigURL -Value "http://proxy.domain.com/proxies/proxy.pac" -Force} -argumentlist $sid

}
```

This is how it would work if the user was not currently log in on XP:

```
$defaultprofilepath = "C:\documents and settings"
$username = "username"
$profilepath = "$defaultprofilepath\$username"
$credential = Get-Credential
Foreach($machine in $computers){

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $machine -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock {reg load "HKU\TempDir" "$($args[0])\NTUSER.DAT"; reg add "HKU\TempDir\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v AutoConfigURL /t REG_SZ /d 'http://proxy.domain.com/proxies/proxy.pac' /f; reg unload "HKU\TempDir"} -argumentlist $profilepath

}
```

P.S. If someone has a clue if there is a powershell cmdlet to load registry hives please comment, i could not find one on the fly

Comment: Paul,     Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'HKU' does not exist.     
ERROR:     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (HKU:String)     [New-ItemProperty], DriveNotFoundException
ERROR:     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemPropertyCommand
ERROR:     + PSComputerName        : nci-xp1

Comment: I noticed on the xp machine I am trying to update that there is no psdrive called HKU.  Only HKCU and HKLM.

Comment: Have you tried running new-psdrive as suggested in the update above?

Comment: HKU                                                  HKEY_USERS                                                              nci-xp1
ERROR: Cannot find path 'HKU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings' because it does not exist.

Comment: It looks like the SID is missing Paul    'HKU:\$sid\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings'    Where would I declard the $sid var?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63295/discussion-between-kent-and-paul).

Comment: Although we ran it without errors, it still did not update the registry on the xp machine.  I was looking at the wrong machine that already had the setting :(.  Hopefully I will catch you tomorrow.  Thanks man.

Comment: `$args[0]` must be put in a subexpression when used inside a string (`"$($args[0])"`), otherwise it would be expanded like this: `"$args" + '[0]'`.

Comment: right, thats what happens if you write scripts at 4 am. i have corrected it

Comment: No love Paul.  it is coming up with this error(looks like it is ignoring your $($args[0])...**ERROR: Cannot find path 'HKU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings' because it does not exist.**

Comment: did you make sure there is actually a value in $sid?

Comment: Ok.  The Windows 7 machine is updating now but the xp machine is still not updating. :(

Comment: It keeps referencing the local sid for the xp machine, instead of the remote sid.  Sid S-1-5-21-557486866-382535363-1543835964-1109 is my sid on my workstation.  The remote users sid is different.  Cannot find path 'HKU:\S-1-5-21-557486866-382535363-1543835964-1109\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings' because it does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for all you help Paul!  You are a very valuable asset to this community!

Answer (score 0):

Using WMI you could do it like this:

```
$computers = ...

$user   = New-Object Security.Principal.NTAccount($env:USERNAME)
$sid    = $user.Translate([Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).Value
$subkey = "$sid\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
$url    = 'http://proy.domain.com/proxies/proxy.pac'
$HKU    = [convert]::ToUInt32('0x80000003', 16)

$credential = Get-Credential
foreach ($machine in $computers) {
  $reg = Get-WmiObject -List -Namespace 'root/default' -Computer $machine `
           -Credential $credential | ? { $_.Name -eq 'StdRegProv' }
  $reg.SetStringValue($HKU, $subkey, 'AutoConfigURL', $url) | Out-Null
}
```

Note, however, that for remote WMI access you need administrative privileges on the remote host. Without admin privileges you could use `Invoke-Command` for local WMI access on the remote host:

```
foreach ($machine in $computers) {
  Invoke-Command -Computer $machine -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock {
    $reg = Get-WmiObject -List -Namespace 'root/default' |
             ? { $_.Name -eq 'StdRegProv' }
    $reg.SetStringValue($args[0], $args[1], 'AutoConfigURL', $args[2]) | Out-Null
  } -ArgumentList $HKU, $subkey, $url
}
```

Note also that only domain accounts have the same SID accross hosts. For local accounts you need to determine the SID of the account on the remote host:

```
foreach ($machine in $computers) {
  Invoke-Command -Computer $machine -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock {
    $user   = New-Object Security.Principal.NTAccount($args[0])
    $sid    = $user.Translate([Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).Value
    $subkey = "$sid\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"

    $reg = Get-WmiObject -List -Namespace 'root/default' |
             ? { $_.Name -eq 'StdRegProv' }
    $reg.SetStringValue($args[1], $subkey, 'AutoConfigURL', $args[2]) | Out-Null
  } -ArgumentList $env:USERNAME, $HKU, $url
}
```

If the account in question *is* a domain account, you may want to provide the domain name when creating the `NTAccount` object, because otherwise you'd be getting the wrong account/SID when there's a local account with the same name as the domain account.

```
$user = New-Object Security.Principal.NTAccount($env:USERDOMAIN, $env:USERNAME)
$sid  = $user.Translate([Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).Value
```

Comment: Ansgar,  if I try your first example, all the variables are filling in with my local workstation info.  I need it to fill in logged in user on the remote system in my $computers variable.  Please advise.

Comment: When I move the variables into the for each loop, the remote machine, updates correctly if it is Windows 7.  It fails for Windows Xp, which is of course the machines that need this reg hack.

Comment: So that is the problem..XP.  Any idea why the reg value would update on windows 7 and not XP?  I know the machine has Powershell 2.0 and winrm on it.

Comment: @Kent Did you try running the scriptblock locally on an XP machine? What is the result? Is PowerShell remoting enabled on the XP host? Do you have a workgroup or a domain environment?

Comment: @Kent I advise you to answer *all* of the questions I asked.

Comment: If I run it locally, it works perfectly.  Had to remove the credentials.  This is a domain environment.  When I run the winrm : PS C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator> winrm quickconfig
WinRM already is set up to receive requests on this machine.
WinRM already is set up for remote management on this machine.

Comment: @Kent Since you have a domain environment: drop this entirely, because it's an utter waste of everyone's time. Deploy the setting either with a logon script (they run locally in the context of the current user), or via [Group Policy Preferences](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731892%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) in case the XP clients have the GPP client side extensions installed. If you don't have domain admin privileges: ask one of your domain admins to do it for you.

Comment: I will start breaking through the silo and see if they will institute the changes.