# How can I run a command with pipe character in its parameters via powershell?

Tags: powershell, parsing

I wish to run the command:

```
mocha -i -g 'database|network|skip'
```

With the pipe being part of the arguments to mocha. However powershell thinks 'network' is a program that I am trying to pipe to:

```
network : The term 'network' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path
```

was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Some research mentioned [the `--%` operator to stop Powershell parsing](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847892.aspx)

> STOP PARSING:  --%
>         The stop-parsing symbol (--%), introduced in Windows PowerShell 3.0,
>         directs Windows PowerShell to refrain from interpreting input as 
>         Windows PowerShell commands or expressions.

however running:

```
mocha --% -i -g 'database|network|skip'
```

Still gives the same error. Which makes sense, since:

> The stop-parsing symbol is effective only until the next newline or 
>      pipeline character.

**How can I run a command with a pipe symbol in powershell?**

**Edit:** Image attached for person who refuses to believe me even after issue has been replicated, and answered by two people:

[image]

Comment: Can not reproduce this on v5.1 or v2.

Comment: @PetSerAl I can, reliably, on powershell `5.1.14393.82`

Comment: Can you provide [mcve]?

Comment: @PetSerAl Yes. My example is already tiny, but try `mocha -g 'a|b'`

Comment: Your example is not complete. It depends from `mocha` command, which can (and likely) be the sourse of error.

Comment: @PetSerAl Try any other PE executable. Not powershell inbuilts. Please read the error in the question - the response being returned is from powershell, not mocha, ie mocha itself is not the source of the error.

Comment: @PetSerAl No. As shown in the question I am using powershell. Hence the powershell error. Please read the actual question.

Comment: Downvoters care to explain why?

Comment: Powershell is eating the quotes is it not? So when mocha gets it there is an unquoted string? `mocha -i -g "'database|network|skip'"`. This _should_ have nothing to do with Powershell and the pipe.

Comment: @matt Running this: 'network' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: That is a cmd error and not a PowerShell one though. I was able to test the with `find`... hmmmm. Perhaps we need to reverse the quotes? `mocha -i -g '"database|network|skip"'`

Comment: @matt yes `mocha -i -g '"database|network|skip"'` works. I'll add this to the answer and credit you.

Comment: This has already been done.

Comment: @matt yep I did it immediately. 

Comment: @mikemaccana Can you start clean PowerShell session (`powershell -noprofile`) and show screenshot of errors for `mocha -i -g 'database|network|skip'` and `mocha --% -i -g 'database|network|skip'` commands?

Comment: @PetSerAl Done. Note the second command isn't complete hence continues onto new line.

Comment: @mikemaccana Now look at your screenshot yourself: error message in screenshot does not math error message in your post. Error message in screenshot does not highlighted in red color as should PowerShell error message, also it does not formatted as PowerShell error message, so it is not PowerShell error message, but output from `mocha` command. If you try different command instead of `mocha`, then you can see it yourself: `cmd -i -g 'database|network|skip' /c echo No error`.

Comment: @PetSerAl 'mocha' definitely does *not* generate 'network is not recognizes as an internal or external command'. **Can you please stop messaging me?** Yes, running in a profile-less powershell gives a different error than running in a .ps1 file. However the question is now answered and this conversation isn't adding anything. Thanks.

Comment: @PetSerAl Also could you please not downvote questions because other people have answered them? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using an example with `find` you will get similar results.

```
find /c "this|that|andtheotherthing" C:\temp\EventCombMT.txt
```

```
find : FIND: Parameter format not correct
At line:1 char:1
+ find /c "this|that|andtheotherthing" C:\temp\EventCombMT.txt
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (FIND: Parameter format not correct:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Pretty sure this is because the quotes are consumed by the PowerShell interpreter and that leave your `mocha` command with an unquoted string. Doubling up the quotes is another was to prevent this.

```
find /c '"this|that|andtheotherthing"' C:\temp\EventCombMT.txt
```

It seems this is not the case with mocha? In comments it was determined that we need to reverse the quote set from that seen in the `find` examples.

There are better ways to call external commands as you have seen in [your linked post](http://edgylogic.com/blog/powershell-and-external-commands-done-right/). Like using the call operator and a hashtable. You would still have to address the quotes though. You could escape a set of double quotes as well to get a similar effect.

```
find /c "`"this|that|andtheotherthing`"" C:\temp\EventCombMT.txt
```

For this to be correct though it does not really match the error you are getting. While I am correct about a solution I might be wrong about my interpretation of the issue. PowerShell should not care about the pipe character regardless of how it is quoted. That is what the quotes are for.

Comment: No.. your right... I mixed up my errors with yours.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [PowerShell and external commands done right](http://edgylogic.com/blog/powershell-and-external-commands-done-right/). You can quote the pipe character to stop powershell treating it as a pipe. In this case:

```
mocha -g 'network"|"database"|"skip'
```

Works perfectly. As @matt has since mentioned, you can also run the (much neater):

```
mocha -i -g '"database|network|skip"'
```

Comment: I'm curious, would the same work the other way around `"network'|'database'|'skip"`

Comment: @Nkosi that would fail (and does fail in testing) since double quotes are not as strict as single quotes. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967407/whats-the-difference-between-single-quote-and-double-quote-to-define-a-string-i