# How can I pass an array as an argument to a PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, ansible

In Ansible, I have an array like this:

```
tab:
  - 'val1'
  - 'val2'
```

And I want to execute a remote script like this:

```
- name: launch Script
  script: "scripts/script.ps1 -tab {{ tab }}"
```

But the json format is not well recognized (`[uval1 uval2]`). I have to convert it to a PowerShell format:

```
$new_tab =  $tab -replace '"','' -replace ']','' -replace '\[','' -split ","
```

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use `join()`

```
scripts/script.ps1 -tab {{ tab | join(',') }}
```

and then it will create a string like this: val1,val2

Comment: What about escaping?

Comment: i suggest you raise a new question, instead of asking a question in the comments

Answer (score 1):

To complement [4c74356b41's useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51135262/11942268):

If you have to preserve the quotes of your list elements, you can use the following logic:

```yaml
- name: launch Script
  script: "scripts/script.ps1 -tab {{ '\"' + tab | join('\",\"') + '\"' }}"
```

This will add double quotes to each element and PowerShell will be able to evaluate each string (e. g. expanding variables etc. ([read more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71741394/11942268))). If you want to wrap your elements in single quotes instead, you can do it like this:

```yaml
- name: launch Script
  script: "scripts/script.ps1 -tab {{ "'" + tab | join("','") + "'" }}"
```

Be aware that the `quote` filter is not useful in this case, as it is designed for shell usage and will not quote every string.