# Execute SSH commands on Idrac interface

Tags: powershell, ssh, automation, scripting

I'm trying to change some network settings on a server with Idrac via powershell script.
The commands by itself work good but when trying to use variables on the script it fails.

The connection is made from the local machine itself.

I guess the issue are on the variables not being picked up correctly.

```
$idrac_iploopback = 169.254.0.1
$dns1 = 1.1.1.1
$dns1 = 8.8.8.8

$hosts_idrac = @{
    "HOSTNAME1" = @{"IP" = "192.168.1.200"; "MASK" = "255.255.255.0"; "GW" = "192.168.1.1"; "dns1" = $dns1; "dns2" = $dns2};
}
$idrac_ip_cust = $hosts_idrac.$servername.IP
$idrac_mask_cust = $hosts_idrac.$servername.MASK
$idrac_gw_cust = $hosts_idrac.$servername.GW
$idrac_dns1_cust = $hosts_idrac.$servername.dns1
$idrac_dns2_cust = $hosts_idrac.$servername.dns2

 #SSH connection with command input.
 ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' root@$idrac_iploopback 'set iDRAC.IPv4.Address $($idrac_ip_cust)'
 ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' root@$idrac_iploopback 'set iDRAC.IPv4.Netmask $($idrac_mask_cust)'
 ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' root@$idrac_iploopback 'set iDRAC.IPv4.Gateway $($idrac_gw_cust)'
 ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' root@$idrac_iploopback 'set iDRAC.IPv4.DHCPEnable 0'
 ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' root@$idrac_iploopback 'set iDRAC.IPv4.DNSFromDHCP 0'
 ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' root@$idrac_iploopback 'set iDRAC.IPv4.DNS1 $($idrac_dns1_cust)'
 ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' root@$idrac_iploopback 'set iDRAC.IPv4.DNS2 $($idrac_dns2_cust)'
```

Any suggestion on how to make it work or another way to do it?

**Output**: (The commands are not being recognised)

ERROR: RAC947: Invalid object value specified.
Make sure to specify the value depending on the type of object.
For more information, see RACADM help.

Comment: Single quotes `'` [are different](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.3) from double quotes `"` in Powershell.

Comment: The error says "Invalid Object" so error means one of the variables starting with a dollar sign is null or in a wrong format.  So I think $hosts_idrac.$servername.IP should be $hosts_idrac.servername.IP with one dollar sign, not two.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between single quote and double quote to define a string in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967407/whats-the-difference-between-single-quote-and-double-quote-to-define-a-string-i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it helps somebody.
It's possible to do it but double quote is needed instead of the single quote.
the double dollar must be present.

Example to change DNS on Idrac from scripting powershell:

```
ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' root@$idrac_iploopback "set iDRAC.IPv4.DNS1 $($your_variable)"
```